# Open different pages when login in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to create a login form with Ionic 4 to display clients.Here what I have:
[image]

I have two types of clients:Technic and Owner.
When a user login there will open a page that dipends on type of client.
If client is Technic it will open the Technic page,and if the client is Owner it will open the Owner page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very basic but hope it helps:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
goToPage(user){
    let page = user.type === UsertTypes.Technic ? '/technic': '/owner;
    this.router.navigateByUrl(page);
}
```